# In for loop, in C language, variable int i has different value then expected

Tags: c

Can you please help me why `int i` becomes -4912 (see the picture) when it should start from 1? Thank you very much.

```c
int main(void)
{
    long long n = 4003600000000014;
    int i;
    int num;
    for (i = 1; i < 15; i += 2)
    {
        int digit = (n / pow(10, i));
        printf("%i\n", digit);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you `#include`s. Yes, they matter.

Comment: *When* do you check the value of `i`? Before it's assigned to by the `for` loop? What happens if you step once in the debugger?

Comment: Is an `int` on your system large enough to hold the values returned by that equation?

Comment: Seems that `i` isn't initialized yet. Make sure the break point is at line 19

Comment: The first chapters of any C programming book typically addresses numerical limits of integers. Do you think that 4003600000000014 / 10^1 will fit inside an int?

Comment: line 3 doesnt initilize `i` so it gets a random stack value until it is set to 1 in the for-loop.

Comment: Thank you it seems to gets a value, until it is set to 1

Answer (score 3):

In your picture, the debugger is *at* the for loop. At that point the for loop initialization has not happened yet and `i` will have an arbitrary value.

Tell the debugger to "step". The initialization of the for loop will then be executed and you will see that`i` is now 1.

Answer (score -1):

you should use %d in your printf and not %i I think.

Just try to initialise i : int i = 0; for example

or declare i in your loop : for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)

Comment: They're equivalent. `%d` is more common, but `%i` works fine.

Comment: yeah, with some researches i saw it. thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/) you can read more about uninitialized variables.
But as a short summary. A variable gets whatever random value is in the memory location until it is set. C/C++ does not initialize variables to 0 by default, it is the responsibility of the programmer.
Uninitialized variables are sources to many bugs and are usually pointed out by compilers if the warnings are configured to be on.